# Replacing the base-href in Index page Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, iis, devops, angular6

We have deployed one web site and under that we deployed one more app (application in IIS) in different app pools both have angular code.

In "Application" code (angular), i need to update the **base href** and other .ts files to /**ApplicationName**.

The code which is deployed in Application is used as **site** in other place so i want to use the different copy of the code.

So i was thinking if we have any option to **dynamically update the base href** -

Below is the options i thought -

- In the Dev ops pipeline, i will add the batch file which will update once the code is built in the build server,

Is it a good option ? If so, we can replace the base href in the built Angular code ?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not.

`angular.json` offers a `basHref` property that you can control through your environments.

If you're on Angular 16+, and you don't have environments, run `npx ng generate environments` to get two.

You can then update your `angular.json` file to create a third one, and when building, you'll be able to run `npx ng build -c myEnvironment`. This will build the app and use the href you have provided in the environment config.

Comment: I am using Angular 12

Comment: Then you already have the environments installed and do not need to run the given command, the rest applies equally across all versions.

Comment: any option there in the IIS for the same without changing the code in Angular ?

Comment: I don't know, I use Angular, not IIS, try asking on their tag [tag:iis]. Nontheless, you have your answer, so maybe try it ?